Getting Started
How does one get started with philosophy, and at what point does someone go from being a philosophy enthusiast to an actual philosopher? Has every thought already been thought?

Look for questions asking for reading lists on this forum - answers there may be useful.

Think about philosophy and have one reasonable new idea about it. That's what makes you a philosopher.

Re your question, “At what point does someone go from being a philosophy enthusiast to an actual philosopher?”, consider the sorites paradox.

This question is similar to: Most effective ways to self-learn philosophy. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For qestions like this, I recommend, as a starting point, Will Durant’s The Story of Philosophy. Published almost a century ago, Story has stood the test of time and holds up very well.
I have never gotten feedback to this answer, which I have now offered five or six times. Please post a reply to this in the comments if you read the book and it is useful to you.

much appreciated i shall give it a read :]

(a) Durant was one of my starting or at least early books. (b) As you may remember, I've recommended/agreed with your recommendedation in the past (c) I still think it a good book... However It was a west-restricted presentation even in the 1930s when it was written. In fact it's intro says so Which is what prompted my complementary answer. (No ± 1 from my side)

Most of the greatest philosophers have been more 'enthusiast' (or friend, lover, liver?) of philosophy rather than philosopher.
Socrates is a prime example. In his time the word for philosophy was σοφιστής — sophist, ie. a professional dealer in knowledge.
He insisted on distinguishing himself from the other philosophers by adding  φίλος — friendly love.
Better to stay an enthusiast than a professional philosopher1.
The alternative quickly becomes philosophology.
Philosophy vs Western Philosophy
Mostly what is called 'philosophy' is really western philosophy. But to claim that philosophy is a western product exclusively is as absurd as claiming that eating, drinking, living, loving and dying are western actions. IOW philosophy is universal to humanity and the only thing western about it is the word philosophy. But then one should write
φιλοσοφία not 'philosophy'!!
Here are some starters for a wider look than just the west.
A more specific suggestion I would make is the Bhagavad Gita which is one of the premier texts for balancing (in your words) enthusiasm and wisdom
The following table may help to contextualize it for an English-speaking audience:



Sanskrit
English




karma
purposive action


bhakti
enthusiasm, passion — religiosity


jnana  also spelt gyana
clear impartial wisdom ie. philosophy!



Note: I dont think that an exclusive western focus is wrong. It's just that if you don't know that, somebody will tell you

1 unless your intent is tenure

How "aham brahmasmi" can be derived from philosophy ? Knowing and realization are different

@quanity You could say such mahavakyas are not western philosophy derivable. But (a) there have been non dualists even among western philosophers (b) Even in Eastern philosophy, to focus on that without the larger Upanishadicc context is a mistake. Ultimately jnana is about 'knowing' reality personally. Until it is known, the testimony of sages, scriptures can be used as a prop. Remember Bh. Gita teaches jnana as a marg a pathway not an endpoint. As a path it can be said to coincide with philosophy

Could you send the email @quanity??

any comment on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEtf9kud5p4      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY4ZB7NNJ1M
